# What was the default working on layered navigation in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, layered-navigation, filter

I need to check the default working of layered navigation filter in Magento 2.

For configurable products color filtering was applied correctly, but when I have added a custom attribute filter, the rendered result is not correct.

Can anyone please help me to find the default working of layered navigation filter for configurable products?

Color attribute is already on the left side of the listing page. Added a custom attribute 'Select' with Yes/No drop-down options. Created some configurable products. Then assign Yes/No to the associated products.

Eg:

Product 1:(Configurable)
    Pro 11  (Color-white, Select-yes)
    Pro 12  (Color-blue, Select-no)
    Pro 13  (Color-red, Select-no)
    Pro 14  (Color-green, Select-yes)

Product 2:(Configurable)
    Pro 21  (Color-white, Select-no)
    Pro 22  (Color-blue, Select-yes)
    Pro 23  (Color-red, Select-yes)
    Pro 24  (Color-green, Select-no)

Product 3:(Configurable)
    Pro 31  (Color-white)
    Pro 32  (Color-blue)
    Pro 33  (Color-red)
    Pro 34  (Color-green)

In front end, choose color filter as white. It results with Product 1, Product 2, Product 3 Then choose Select filter as Yes. It results with Product 1 & Product 2. Why it results with 2 products. The correct answer is color -white & select-yes is Product 1.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please describe your problem and your goal in more detail. What exactly did you add? How is the result not correct? I don't even understand the question "what was the default working".

Comment: updated my question